# GDAL point ordering (difference in version 2.2 and 3.0) Python

Tags: python, gdal

I'm currently trying to update some legacy Python code from gdal version 2.2.3 to 3.0.2, (along with python 2 > python 3)

I need to generate contours and unpack the points, along the lines of:

```
_, output = gdal.ContourGenerate( .... )
points_list = [contour.GetGeometryRef().GetPoints() for contour in output]
```

Now `points_list` contains the <del>same</del> very similar points for each contour, regardless of version. However the ordering is changed between 2.2.3 and 3.0.2

Python list comprehension preserves the order provided by the object being iterated. So unless `GetPoints` is unordered, I don't think this is a python issue.

Can anyone suggest a way to dictate the ordering generated by `GetPoints`? Or point me at the change log for this behaviour, so I can figure out what's happened?

Comment: Have you checked if gdal.ContourGenerate returns  similarly ordered contours with both versions?

Comment: @user30184 no it doesn't appear to. Both the order of the contour and the points within are in a different order.

Comment: There are lots of changes to contouring since 2.2.3 https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/NEWS. I believe they are improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the link. No doubt they are improvements! Just wanting to make sure my code leverages the improvements correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Your observation may be related with the change in the order of the points in polygons that is discussed in gdal-dev mailing list thread https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2021-February/053534.html. You seem to deal with contour lines but maybe the process is first building polygons in some previous step. Even if your issue was not the same it could be that pushing the geometries through the geometry normalizing function in the sama way than in this pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/3506 could help with keeping the order of the points uniform.

The new OGR_G_Normalize() is using GEOS and it does the same thing as ST_Normalize in PostGIS https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Normalize.html